# Remove class from <a> button after pressing another <a> button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a site, on which you can download a file by pressing an  button. The thing is, that I want people to click another  button first to subscribe to a youtube channel and THEN to be able to download the file. So, I have to get rid of the disabled class on the download button after pressing the subscribe button. Here below is my code, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Tried all the answers now, none did work. I'm getting this error, what does that mean?

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at index.html:23

Line 23 is

> $('#sub').on('click',function(event){

```js
$('#sub').on('click',function()){
  $('#dl').removeClass('disabled');
});
```

```css
.disabled {opacity: 0.8; cursor: not-allowed;}
.size-3 {font-size: 16px;}
.btn {
  font: 100%/1.1 "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border: 2.2px solid #ecf0f1;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 12px 62px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 3px 6.9px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<a id="sub" href="#" class="btn size-3">Subscribe to ZERO</a>
<a id="dl" href="#" class="btn size-3 disabled">Download Exyther</a>
```

Comment: Did you run the code you pasted into the snippet, and look at the console output, which very clearly shows a syntax error?

Comment: You may want to add the attribute "disabled" to your elements, as on mobile they will still be clickable

Comment: Not sure about trying to force your users to subscribe. I think is better to motivate the users to subscribe instead.

Comment: You don't have jQuery loaded - so it doesn't recognise the $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qrc3qm2e/

I have added extra code to check if the button shouldn't be clickable, if you need a jQuery answer please follow this link https://jsfiddle.net/qrc3qm2e/1/

Javascript

```
var subElement = document.getElementById("sub");
var dlElement = document.getElementById("dl");
subElement.onclick = function(event)
{
    dlElement.classList.remove('disabled');
    dlElement.removeAttribute('disabled');
};

dlElement.onclick = function(event)
{
    if(dlElement.className.indexOf('disabled') > -1)
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
};
```

HTML

```
<a id="sub" href="#" target="blank" class="btn size-3">Subscribe to ZERO</a>
<a id="dl" href="#" target="blank" class="btn size-3 disabled" disabled="disabled">Download Exyther</a>
```

Comment: A match made in heaven!

Answer (score 0):

This makes your code an error: `function())` << double close

correct JS

```
$('#sub').on('click',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#dl').removeClass('disabled');
});
```

Comment: @biss add `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: @biss [Check this post, maybe there is your mistake](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

You can help by keeping your example really really simple. We don't need to know about your font for example. : )

You probably want to use a `disabled` property - or that AND style that a bit with CSS. here's how to do that. - if you want to use a link - then the download will be its default behaviour - so you shouldn't have to prevent it - but see @JacobW 's about that. You'd likely not want the URL in the markup - if you are really trying to dissuade them from getting the file until subscribing. If you can't switch out the button for the link - and see the concept, I'm sure you will at some later date. : ) Good Luck!

### JavaScript - and disabled property

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/3t0pn6gv/

markup

```
<button class='one'>one</button>
<button class='two' disabled>two</button>
```

style

```
button:disabled {
  opacity: .3;
}
```

script (not jQuery for @Canvas)

```
var signupButton = document.querySelector('button.one');
var downloadButton = document.querySelector('button.two');

signupButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    downloadButton.disabled = false;
});
```

### with jQuery and CSS class - (not actually disabled... but looks so)

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/wyx1od9g/

markup

```
<button class='one'>one</button>
<button class='two disabled'>two</button>
```

style

```
.disabled{
  opacity: .2;
}
```

script

```
$('button.one').on('click', function() {
  $('button.two').removeClass('disabled');
});
```

Comment: this won't work for anchors because of their default behavior for example click the second button https://jsfiddle.net/3t0pn6gv/2/

Comment: @Canvas - why would there be an anchor there anyway?

Comment: I use anchors as buttons.

Comment: You should probably use the appropriate element for the job.

Comment: That's not what OP asked for

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/jacobweyer/pen/JNzgJE?editors=1111

Here's a codepen of the issue

```js
$('#sub').on('click', function(event){
  if (event.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  
  $('#dl').removeClass('disabled');
});
```

You didn't close the function, but also you can add event into the function. This will pass the click event into your jquery.

With the click event you can actually prevent the page from jumping moving as well by preventing the default action on the a tag.

Comment: @Canvas - because of the tag? I don't think so. They used jQuery.